# How to say to React that data is already updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As you guessed, I'm newbie in JS and especially in React.

I have a variable `list` for saving my calculations. I have one handler for drag-drop and form, but when data is updated, react still doesn't know about that.

**Should I use some special command for update this.props.data or the better way is write all logic in React components?**

btw, `list` consists of `runs[]`. Each `run` have `id` and `balls[]`. The `ball` have `counter` and `value`.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var Table = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return  (<table className='table table-bordered bg-success'>
        {this.props.data.map(function (run){
            return <TablesRun runId={id}/>;
        })}
            </table>);
        }
});

var TablesRun = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return  <tr className='bg-warning'>
                    <td>
                        <span className='badge'>{this.props.runId}</span>ff
                    </td>
                </tr>;
    }
});

React.renderComponent(<Table data={list.runs}/>,
    document.getElementById('runTable'));
```

[image]

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  You mention "drag-drop and form", "data is updated", and some other stuff.. but you only show code for rendering a table.  Please clarify.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand next time don't delete my image and everything will be fine.. I just want to say that list is updating in handler.. and it works fine (you can see the result on the image). But when it will updated, React does nothing.

Comment: I put the image back, but I don't see the point of it without the actual code that's causing things to show up in the console.  There's no console.log in your code.  I don't think there's enough information here to answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you update the `list` variable outside of React components, you need to tell React to render again. React does not use data binding to know that you've modified a variable.

Simply call `React.renderComponent(<Table data={list.runs}/>, document.getElementById('runTable'));` again and React will update the DOM with the new prop value.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use some special command for update this.props.data

Yes, use [setProps](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html) rather than updating the objects directly. However, note the warning on the documentation page: calling `setProps` usually isn't needed, and only works on the root component.